# Clang not creating object files when using plugin

Tags: file, object, plugins, hyperlink, clang

I'm trying to use clang++ instead of g++ to create object files that will later be linked by the gnu linker.

I'm am able to do this successfully using native clang++, but when I use clang++ with a plugin, I get a link error:

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

That's okay! I just need the object files! However, when I specify -S or -c I do not get any object file, even if I use .o to explicitly specify an output file.

I am unable to do this even with clang's example plugins.

How can I get clang to give an object file?

Much Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I had this same issue. For me, replacing "-plugin" with "-add-plugin" on my command line fixed the problem. I'm not sure what the difference is or why it worked, but it did.

Also, if you are using "-cc1" on the command line, try removing it and prefixing every plugin specific argument with "-Xclang ", i.e. "clang -Xclang -load -Xclang plugin.so -Xclang -add-plugin -Xclang pluginName". Again, I'm not sure why -cc1 wasn't working for me, but it wasn't and this fixed it.

Comment: With `-cc1` you also have to provide all include paths and defines, etc. Using `-plugin` will replace the default "compile" action with your plugins action. Using `-add-plugin` will add your plugin to the default "compile" action. But your answer helped a lot!

Comment: You have to beware though that any modification you do to the AST with your plugin will not be carried to the final executable. Plugins currently (3.1, 3.2) cannot modify the AST. The CodeGenAction runs before your plugin and is responsible for generating the final files.